# SparkError:Using collectAsMap()

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I create a broadcast:

```
val broadcastIndex = sc.broadcast(index.collectAsMap())
val Ahit = read.map( (x: String) => {
  val r = broadcastIndex.value.get(3906900).get
  r
}).reduce(_ ++ _)
```

the number "3906900" is an id of one line record in index,and errors as follow:

> 14/12/08 15:30:02 ERROR ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from
>   thread [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-31] shutting down
>   ActorSystem [sparkDriver] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>     at
>   com.google.protobuf_spark.ByteString.toByteArray(ByteString.java:213)
>     at
>   akka.remote.serialization.MessageContainerSerializer.fromBinary(MessageContainerSerializer.scala:59)
>     at
>   akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(Serialization.scala:104)
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)     at
>   akka.serialization.Serialization.deserialize(Serialization.scala:98)
>     at
>   akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.deserialize(MessageSerializer.scala:23)
>     at
>   akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$lzycompute$1(Endpoint.scala:55)
>     at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$1(Endpoint.scala:55)
>     at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.dispatch(Endpoint.scala:73)
>     at
>   akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:764)
>     at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)     at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)  at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)   at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)  at
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>   14/12/08 15:30:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Failed to run collectAsMap at
>   App.scala:183 Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job cancelled because SparkContext
>   was shut down     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:694)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:79)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor.postStop(DAGScheduler.scala:1399)
>     at
>   akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.akka$actor$dungeon$FaultHandling$$finishTerminate(FaultHandling.scala:201)
>     at
>   akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.terminate(FaultHandling.scala:163)
>     at akka.actor.ActorCell.terminate(ActorCell.scala:338)  at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:431)     at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:447)    at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:262)     at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:218)  at
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

Could somebody tells me how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: Looks to me like it's the first statement that has the problem `Failed to run collectAsMap at App.scala:183 `. Since collectAsMap turns an RDD into a normal Map, presumably the result is huge and doesn't fit in memory. You should change your code to work directly on the RDD and not convert it into a Map? How big is the `index` RDD?

Comment: Like what? If it's not going to fit, it's not going to fit. Back up one step and tell us what your use-case is overall - maybe there's another solution.

Comment: @Paul If I don't convert it into a Map it would give me a feedback like this: Scala MacthError: null.The index is more than 6 gigabyte and my memory is 16 gigabyte.Is that possible to deal with the index?

Comment: I repeat myself. Please tell us what your use-case is - what computation you are trying to do. Probably there's another way of doing it that doesn't require the in-memory Map